# How to make the absolute element doesn't effect width of page when open responsive tool on browser?

Tags: html, css

[image]I have a task to make a layout like this:

I make this by setting position relative for the wrap and position absolute for 2 small stick div. the problem is when I open the dev tool on google and try to responsive this design. I see the max-width of the screen is not correct. It increases because I'm set on top of 1 stick div that is too big ( but I must do this to make the design correct ).

So, what I can do to due with this situation? I cant show the code but if someone comments I will explain more. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a width of 100vw (view width = the width of your browser layout) and hide the overflow-x on your to fix your problem.

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Just be warned this is not a great solution to any horizontal overflow as it's better to fix it than hiding it.

Comment: hi @med, I already do that, but when you open the dev tool the overflow is not working, you can touch and wrap horizontally as mobile. And that is the problem.